# Unable to hide and show element on check box click event for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show and hide on check box click event based on the checked condition of the check box. But for the first time unable to show and hide elements. The same script works for the second time when the click event occurs. The script is as follows.

```
$(document).on("click", ".check-now-checkbox", function() {
              if($(this).prop('checked')===true){
               $("#Password").show();
                  $("#save_password").show();
                        $("#Role").removeClass("show-pwd");
                    }
              else{
                  $("#Password").hide()
                  $("#save_password").hide();

                        $("#Role").addClass("show-pwd");
              }
            });
```

Html code for the above script as follows.

```
<div class="password"><div class="row server-inputs" id="Password">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="password" type="password" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true" name="password" maxlength="255" value="">
<label name="password" data-error="This field is required" data-success="" for="Password">Password</label>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="save_password"><div class="row server-inputs" id="save_password">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in check-now-checkbox" name="save_password" id="Save password?" checked="checked" style="cursor:pointer">
<label for="Save password?" style="margin-top: -35px;cursor: pointer;">Save password?</label>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to hide "div#save_password" and use change event on checkbox rather click.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".check-now-checkbox", function() {
              if($(this).prop('checked')===true){
               $("#Password").show();
                        $("#Role").removeClass("show-pwd");
                    }
              else{
                  $("#Password").hide()
                        $("#Role").addClass("show-pwd");
              }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="password">
    <div class="row server-inputs" id="Password">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true" name="password" maxlength="255" value="">
            <label name="password" data-error="This field is required" data-success="" for="Password">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="save_password">
    <div class="row server-inputs" id="save_password">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in check-now-checkbox" name="save_password" id="Save password?" checked="checked" style="cursor:pointer">
            <label for="Save password?" style="margin-top: -35px;cursor: pointer;">Save password?</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".check-now-checkbox").click(function(){
    If($(this).is(":checked")){
        $("#Password").show(); 
        $("#save_password").show(); 
        $("#Role").removeClass("show-pwd"); 
    }
else{
      $("#Password").hide() 
      $("#save_password").hide(); 
      $("#Role").addClass("show-pwd"); 
}

});
```